Can't compile or use npm run dev or watch b/c of an error msg
Every time I try to run npm run watch or prod in git bash, I am getting an error msg.  Here's what my error looks like. Please help!
$ npm run watch

> xx-react@2023.4.3 watch C:\CodeBase\JavaScript\react
> node ../script/build.js watch react

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^    
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:
- C:\CodeBase\JavaScript\script\build.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
 ............
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\CodeBase\\JavaScript\\script\\build.js' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xx-react@2023.4.3 watch: `node ../script/build.js watch react`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xx-react@2023.4.3 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-12T17_47_40_775Z-debug.log

